# mdframed breaks vskip option in quoting

Tags: spacing, mdframed, quoting

Csonsider the following MWE. Without the call to `\surroundwithmdframed`, the `vskip` argument to `quoting` works. With it, it doesn't. Can anyone suggest a workaround or fix? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames, rgb, svgnames, x11names, sections]{xcolor}
\usepackage[vskip=10in]{quoting}
\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt, backgroundcolor=LightGray]{quoting}
\begin{document}
Some content
\begin{quoting}
  xx
\end{quoting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case, i wouldn't use quoting at all. You don't need it. Define an `mdframed`-environment called `quoting` instead.

Answer (score 4):

An easy work-around would be to supply the skip as part of the options to an [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) environment. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) mentions the following lengths:

[image]

As such, also supply `skipabove=10in` and `skipbelow=10in`. However, I'd use the power of `mdframed` and create your own `mdquoting` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames, rgb, svgnames, x11names, sections]{xcolor}
\usepackage[vskip=2\baselineskip]{quoting}
\newmdenv[
  linewidth=2pt,
  backgroundcolor=LightGray,
  skipabove=2\baselineskip,
  skipbelow=2\baselineskip,
  innerleftmargin=2.5em,
  innerrightmargin=2.5em]{mdquoting}
\begin{document}
Some content
\begin{quoting}
  xx
\end{quoting}
Some content
\begin{mdquoting}
  xx
\end{mdquoting}
Some content
\end{document}
```

Comment: Funny, using `\surroundwithmdframed[linewidth=2pt, skipabove=5in, skipbelow=5in, backgroundcolor=LightGray]{quoting}` produces a space at the top, but no space below. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Yes. Another reason to use a fully-contained [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) solution.

Comment: Any idea what the problem is?